# Navigate to children module from App Module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I have an app component where I need to click the button to navigate to the login screen, which is in the main component. Main Component is in main module, that is child to app module.

Here is how looks like app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MainModule} from  './main/main.module'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MainModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is main.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [],
})
export class MainModule {}
```

Here is app-routing.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './main/login/login.component'

const routes: Routes = [{path: './main/login', component: LoginComponent}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here I define the route to login component.

And in component, I try to navigate to login like this
`<button mat-raised-button class="btn-default" [routerLink]="['./main/login']">Log in</button>`

But get this error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'main/login'
> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'main/login'

How I need to set up routing correctly?

Comment: The defined routes `path` should not start with `./`. Try just setting `main/login`. Also, the router link should most likely be absolute not relative to your current location (`[routerLink]="['/main/login']`).

Answer (score 1):

Routes shouldn't be defined with "." nor with "/" prefix,
therefore consider modifying `routes` as follows:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: "main",
  children: [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
  ]
}]
```

Next modify your login button as below:

```html
<button [routerLink]="['/main/login']">
```

Optionally on sibling routes (children of main)

```html
<button [routerLink]="['./login']">
```

Comment: it change the route in the browser, but not redir4ct me to component

Comment: How did you write your link? relatively?

Comment: I write it like this `<button [routerLink]="['/main/login']">`

Comment: have you defined the route array like I did?